Unexpected behaviour in seaborn subplots when the x axis is being shared
I am having trouble using the sharex=True when I create two graphs with seaborn that should share the same horizontal axis.
I have my example hereafter and even with sharex=False I get a warning that I cannot interpret.
I print below the xticklabels and they are not as expected. Any help to solve the mystery is anticipated with great joy...
# Generate the years and random integers for 'total' and 'new', where 'total' > 'new' and calculate the cumulative sum for 'trend'
years = np.arange(2000, 2024)
np.random.seed(0)  # Set seed for reproducibility
new_values = np.random.randint(1, 11, size=len(years))
total_values = np.random.randint(2, 21, size=len(years))
total_values = np.maximum(total_values, new_values + 1)
trend_values = np.cumsum(new_values)

# DataFrame
example = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': years,
    'new': new_values,
    'total': total_values,
    'trend': trend_values
})

# Work on the graph
total_color = 'steelblue'
new_drugs_color = 'skyblue'

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex = False, figsize = (10,7), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [3, 1.5]})

bottom, top = 2000, 2023

sns.barplot(example, x = 'year', y = 'total', facecolor = total_color, edgecolor = total_color, lw=1.8, width=0.7, ax=axes[0])
bottomplot = sns.barplot(example, x = 'year', y = 'new', color = new_drugs_color, edgecolor = total_color, lw=1.8, width=0.7, hatch="//", ax = axes[0])
topbar = plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1,fc = total_color, edgecolor = total_color, lw=1.8)
bottombar = patches.Rectangle((0,0),1,1, facecolor = new_drugs_color, edgecolor = total_color, lw=1.8, hatch="////")
axes[0].set_ylim(top = example['total'].max() + 8)
axes[0].margins(y=0.01)

l = axes[0].legend([topbar, bottombar], ['total', 'newly appeared'], ncol = 1, prop={'size':7}, loc = 'upper left')
l.draw_frame(False)

percentages = []
for total, new in zip(axes[0].containers[0].datavalues, axes[0].containers[1].datavalues):
    percentages.append(f'''{int(new *100 / total)}%''')
# print(percentages)

axes[0].bar_label(axes[0].containers[0], fontsize=8, color = total_color, rotation = 0, padding = 15, fontweight='bold')
axes[0].bar_label(axes[0].containers[0], labels = axes[0].containers[1].datavalues.astype(int), fontsize=8, color = new_drugs_color, rotation = 0, padding = 5, fontweight='bold')
axes[0].bar_label(axes[0].containers[1], labels = percentages, fontsize=7, color = new_drugs_color, padding = 1.5, rotation = 0, fontstyle='italic')

axes[0].set_xticklabels(axes[0].get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor', fontsize = 8)
axes[0].set_xlabel('', labelpad = 5, loc = 'center', fontsize = 10)

axes[0].set_ylabel("Count of total", labelpad = 15, loc = 'center', fontsize = 10)

axes[1] = sns.lineplot(example, x = 'year', y = 'trend', markers=True, marker="o", legend = 'full', markersize = 4, color=new_drugs_color)
axes[1].set_ylabel('''Trend of new appearances''', labelpad = 15, loc = 'center')
axes[1].set_ylim(top = example['trend'].max() + 10)
axes[1].margins(y=0.01)

axes[1].set_xticklabels(axes[1].get_xticklabels(), rotation=0, ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor', fontsize = 10)
axes[1].set_xlabel("year", labelpad = 5, loc = 'center', fontsize = 10)

plt.xticks(rotation=30, ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor', fontsize = 8)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.title ('''TITLE''', y = 3.4, fontsize = 11, loc = 'left')

print(axes[0].get_xticklabels())
print(axes[1].get_xticklabels())

plt.show()

The graph I get is:

and the warning along with the x_ticklabels are these:
/var/folders/9c/w4pm5s1x1v7bgs372yrqwjfm0000gn/T/ipykernel_97104/101281620.py:44: UserWarning: set_ticklabels() should only be used with a fixed number of ticks, i.e. after set_ticks() or using a FixedLocator.
  axes[0].set_xticklabels(axes[0].get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor', fontsize = 8)
/var/folders/9c/w4pm5s1x1v7bgs372yrqwjfm0000gn/T/ipykernel_97104/101281620.py:54: UserWarning: set_ticklabels() should only be used with a fixed number of ticks, i.e. after set_ticks() or using a FixedLocator.
  axes[1].set_xticklabels(axes[1].get_xticklabels(), rotation=0, ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor', fontsize = 10)
[Text(0, 0, '2000'), Text(1, 0, '2001'), Text(2, 0, '2002'), Text(3, 0, '2003'), Text(4, 0, '2004'), Text(5, 0, '2005'), Text(6, 0, '2006'), Text(7, 0, '2007'), Text(8, 0, '2008'), Text(9, 0, '2009'), Text(10, 0, '2010'), Text(11, 0, '2011'), Text(12, 0, '2012'), Text(13, 0, '2013'), Text(14, 0, '2014'), Text(15, 0, '2015'), Text(16, 0, '2016'), Text(17, 0, '2017'), Text(18, 0, '2018'), Text(19, 0, '2019'), Text(20, 0, '2020'), Text(21, 0, '2021'), Text(22, 0, '2022'), Text(23, 0, '2023')]
[Text(1995.0, 0, '1995'), Text(2000.0, 0, '2000'), Text(2005.0, 0, '2005'), Text(2010.0, 0, '2010'), Text(2015.0, 0, '2015'), Text(2020.0, 0, '2020'), Text(2025.0, 0, '2025')]

Also if I try to use sharex=True, the graph becomes totally messed up.

